# Рандомное изменение положения слайда transtate3d

Tags: javascript, css

Подскажите, пожалуйста. Нужно что бы показывало рандомный слайд. Сейчас 4 слайда и у них 4 значения свойства translate3d -1100', '-2200', '-3300', '-4400, нужно что бы записывалосбь рандомное знечение из этих 4ех.

```
   function arrayRandElement(arr) {
          var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length);
          return arr[rand];
   }
   var arr = ['-1100', '-2200', '-3300', '-4400'];
   var rnd = arrayRandElement(arr);
   var trs = document.getElementsByClassName('v-slider__content');
   trs.style.transform = 'translate3d(rnd)';
```

Переменная rnd если вывести ее в консоль выдает правильное рандомное значение. Нужно теперь как то передать ее в css(translate3d). Консоль выдает ошибку: TypeError: trs.style is undefined

Answer (score 2):

```
[...trs].forEach(item => item.style.transform = 'translate3d(' + rnd + ')');
```

---

```
[...trs].forEach(item => item.style.transform = `translate3d(${rnd})`;
```

```js
setInterval(function() {
  var trs = document.getElementsByClassName("test");
  var arr = [11, 22, 33, 44];
  var rnd = Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length);
  [...trs].forEach(item => {
    item.style.transform = `translate3d(${arr[rnd]}px, 0px, 0px)`;
  });
}, 1000);
```

```css
.test {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background: lightgreen;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="test"></div>
```

Comment: trs.forEach is not a function и то и то

Comment: @ilyaaa521 Пардон.

Comment: Щас ошибок нет, но почему то не хочет работать.... Значение translate3d не меняется